# EM Clustering package for R version 3

Tags: r

I'm looking for an implementation of EM clustering for R.

I've tried to install.packages 'mclust' and 'EMCluster' and they both inform me that they are "not available (for R version 3.1.2)"

Are there any known packages for version 3?

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa ?

Comment: `unname(grep("clust",available.packages()[,"Package"],value=TRUE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are available for R 3.1.2, you may have a different mirror selected.

try this to install:

`install.packages("mclust", repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')`

Comment: That works, thank you very much.